# Should LDPlayer9 be used as an android emulator for mobile app development?

Tags: android, react-native, android-emulator, emulation

So I use Android Studio's emulator for mobile app development using React Native. Recently, came across this "lightweight" android emulator called "LDPlayer9", is this reliable? My styling seems way off compared to results from Android Studio's emulator as well as in XCode's iOS simulators. Should I disregard styling issues seen in LDPlayer9? I even tested my app in actually Android devices, seems like they have similar results with Android Studio and XCode simulators. I only encountered this styling issue in LDPlayer9. Maybe LDPlayer9 is really just an emulator for mobile games? (I am asking because I was told my app had bad styling using this specific emulator)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found out settings were set to tablet mode. LDPlayer’s default layout is in tablet mode. My project isn’t optimized for tablets. If ever you use it, please make sure to check LDPlayer’s settings.